# Recursion logic in Binary Tree Path Sum Problem giving wrong output

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to solve the Path Sum problem using recursion in Leetcode. I am not good at solving questions using recursion. I saw some other solutions, but trying to implement one by myself. I am not understanding what I am doing wrong in my approach. If someone helps me to understand where I am doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Problem statement:
Given the root of a binary tree and an integer targetSum, return true if the tree has a root-to-leaf path such that adding up all the values along the path equals targetSum.

A leaf is a node with no children.

```
class Solution {
    public boolean hasPathSum(TreeNode root, int targetSum) {
        if(checkSum(root, targetSum) == 1) return true;
        return false;
    }
    
    public int checkSum(TreeNode root, int targetSum){
        if(root == null) return 0;
        if(root.left != null){
           // Assuming my checkSum() function already works, I want to get the left tree sum
            int left = checkSum(root.left, targetSum-root.val);
            // Adding the root value to the left tree sum to check if it equals to targetSum
            // If it matches, it returns 1
            if(left+root.val == targetSum){
                return 1;
            };
        }
        if(root.right != null){
           // Assuming my checkSum() function already works, I want to get the right tree sum
            int right = checkSum(root.right, targetSum-root.val);
            // Adding the root value to the right tree sum to check if it equals to targetSum
            // If it matches, it returns 1
            if(right+root.val == targetSum){
                return 1;
            };
        }
        // When everything above, does not match, it returns 0
        return 0;
    }
}
```

My Approach:
I have read while studying about Recursion is that you have to trust that your function works. So believing that I am assuming calling the checkSum(root.left, targetSum - root.val) should return the sum of the left subtree. After that, I am adding the root.val to the left sum and checking if it equals to targetSum. I have done the same thing for the right subtree as well. My function currently gives wrong output. Can someone help me understanding where I am doing wrong with examples. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key problem with your code is that you haven't actually covered the base scenario.
According to your code, when we have reached a leaf, we simply return 0. You do not take into consideration `targetSum` variable at all. Think about it. Imagine a very simple case in which you have a root with two children whose values are 10, 5, 20 respectively and `targetSum = 30`. The answer to this input should true, but you function will return false because it simply ignores the `targetSum` at the bottom of the stack(in other words, the base case).

So, the check for the base case may look like:

```
if (root.left == null && root.right == null) {
    //some logic 
}
```

Aprat from the base check,
the if-statements

```
if(left+root.val == targetSum){
   return 1;
};
if(right+root.val == targetSum){
   return 1;
};
```

are not correct since you `left/right` are the results of checkSum, which returns only 1 or 0. There is no point in adding it to `root.val` as it does not mean a sum along the way to some leaf. I would replace the first if-statement with

```
if (left == 1) {
    return 1;
}
```

The same should be done with the second if-statement.
I hope this will be of help to you.

Comment: Hi, I have tried your suggestion. For example, ``` if(root.left == null && root.right == null){ if(root.val == targetSum) return 1} ```. But it still gives me the wrong output. Maybe I did not get your suggestion correctly. Can you please give one more idea?

Comment: Sure, please look at my updated answer. You should also consider changing the erroneous if-statements.

Comment: It worked perfectly now. Thanks a lot. I accepted your answer.

Comment: Hi, can I ask one more question? I have seen some recursive solution where it checks only `if(root==null) return null` and in other places, it checks `if(root.left) == null && (root.right == null))` as well. Can you share your thought process when you think of the recursive solution of a problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AshequlHaque  Well, there are essentially two steps I take when dealing with problems which imply recursion. The first one is to identify the base case, i.e. the simplest possible scenario. Solutions to these cases are typically easy to find. Examples of these situations are an array with only one element or a tree with just one node. The second step is to figure out how to break down the original problem to smaller ones. To do this, you need to ask yourself questions like 'What if I had results for smaller inputs?'  'If so, what is the relation between the original task and smaller ones?'

Comment: Of course, this skill requires some practice and experience. Hopefully, you got the idea.